# Python Docx Missing first image

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I am currently building a Word Document using python docx library.
In this document I have a header. Within this header, I have a simple table with one row and 3 columns. And in one cell, i put a logo.

Then in my document I put various elements like paragraphs and others images.
And for some reason the first image never displays.

It only shows when i remove the image from the header.

This is how i create my header :

```
section_header = document.sections[0]
header = section_header.header
table_header = header.add_table(2, 3, Inches(6))
table_header.style = 'Table Grid'
table_header._cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run().add_picture('my_logo.png', width=Inches(1))
table_header._cells[1].paragraphs[0].add_run("Some text")
table_header._cells[2].paragraphs[0].add_run("Some text")
```

And this is how i add my others images :

```
document.add_picture('image1.png')
document.add_picture('image2.png')
```

Does someone know why my "image1.png" doesn't display in my Document ?

For now i'm just doubling the first image, but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Are the `my_logo.png` and `image1.png` the same file and it doesn't matter which order it appears in the document? Or does whatever image you place first not show?

Comment: my_logo.png and image1.png are not the same file. I want a specific order for them to appear. And whatever image i place first after the header does not show

Answer (score 0):

I expect what you'll find is that the header becomes so big with the image in it that it *overlaps* the first paragraph of the body and thereby obscures it.

Try putting in a single-pixel (or otherwise quite short) image in the header and see if that doesn't fix it.

The header does not participate in the same "flow container" as the body. In other words, a tall header does not "push down" the start of the body container.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is an issue with python-docx.  I have tried to load the header image then the body image, load the header image at the end of the document creation process and used a template with the header image pre-loaded - all with the same effect - the 1st image does not appear.  I have only been able to solve it in the same way you have, but posting the 1st body image twice.  I agree that this does not seem right.

Comment: I did like scanny said. I added a single pixel image after my header. Since i needed a empty row, i added the pixel to this row. At least i named the pixel "anti_bug_pixel.png". Still not look right but it's easier for someone else to understand the code with the right comment.