# Unwanted SaveAs popup window displays when doc.Close() perform for pywin32com

Tags: ms-word, pywin32, python-docx

I am trying to create Table of Contents for the Word document generated using python-docx module.

```
    paragraph = doc.add_paragraph()
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    fld_char = OxmlElement('w:fldChar') 
    fld_char.set(ns.qn('w:fldCharType'), 'begin')
    instr_text = OxmlElement('w:instrText')
    instr_text.set(ns.qn('xml:space'), 'preserve')
    instr_text.text = 'TOC \\o "1-5" \\h \\z \\u'

    fld_char2 = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
    fld_char2.set(ns.qn('w:fldCharType'), 'separate')
    fld_char3 = OxmlElement('w:t')
    fld_char3.text = "Right-click to update field."
    fld_char3 = OxmlElement('w:updateFields') 
    fld_char3.set(ns.qn('w:val'), 'true')
    fld_char2.append(fld_char3)

    fld_char4 = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
    fld_char4.set(ns.qn('w:fldCharType'), 'end')

    r_element = run._r
    r_element.append(fld_char)
    r_element.append(instr_text)
    r_element.append(fld_char2)
    r_element.append(fld_char4)
```

But i have seen a pop up with yes or no during opening the document.
To avoid the yes or no pop up.
I tried to open the file through pywin32 and tried to update the Table of Contents and trying to save.
While saving facing an issue as saveAs pop windows appears.

```
word = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
word.Visible = False
doc1 = word.Documents.Open(file_name)
doc1.TablesOfContents(1).Update()
doc1.Close(SaveChanges=True)
word.Application.Quit()
```

But i am pretty sure if i could bypass this saveAs issue the application saves successfully without any errors or pop up messages while opening.

```
doc1.Close(False)
```

If i try with SaveChanges = False then yes or no pop is appearing while opening the document.
Please share your thoughts or suggestions to fix the issue while SaveChanges = True. I am assuming document is becoming readonly mode some how. so it is displaying saveAs window.

Document is of 500 pages contains images, tables and text.

**Update:**
After debugging further identified the issue same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68851068/picture-in-header-hide-first-picture-in-docx-with-python-docx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486580/python-docx-missing-first-image)

Any suggestions for the fix? in the second link Scanny mentioned 1 pixel fix which couldn't understand.

Comment: Able to save the document if images are not consider to be part of the document. This is strange. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try setting `Application.DisplayAlerts` to False. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.displayalerts

Comment: Thanks for your time @DS_London. DisplayAlerts = False is not fixing the issue

Comment: Try doc1.Close(SaveChanges=0) ;)